# Find the size of database ldf file

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to use c# code find the ldf file size for a db?

I have a way to find the location of ldf using sql query. then using code find file size as normal way, but i guess there could be potential system permission issue and is there a way to find the size simpler and safer?

thanks.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: using T-SQL query retrieve the ldf location. then get file size, but i believe that's not a good way.

Comment: You could try to use SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [serverName] = @@SERVERNAME,
    [databaseName] =  instance_name,
    dataSizeInKB = SUM(CASE WHEN counter_name = 'Data File(s) Size (KB)' THEN cntr_value END),
    logSizeInKB = SUM(CASE WHEN counter_name = 'Log File(s) Size (KB)' THEN cntr_value END)
FROM 
    sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE 
    counter_name IN ('Data File(s) Size (KB)', 'Log File(s) Size (KB)')
    AND instance_name <> '_Total'
GROUP BY 
    instance_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get transaction log file location and size from either sys.database_files or sys.master_files, then use SqlConnection, SqlCommand from the .NET framework to compose the SQL query, run it with ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader and get requested result.